# Why PCManFM-Qt custom actions are not working

Tags: desktop-shortcuts, pcmanfm

I'm trying to add some custom actions to the PCManFM-Qt contextual menu from this guide on Manjaro wiki. https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=CUSTOM_ACTIONS_FOR_PCmanFM-Qt

Unfortunately none of them are working, I've tested the same thing described there.

There's no error log on `syslog`, `dmesg`, but this log on the `~/.xsession-errors`

```
** (process:24519): CRITICAL **: fm_file_action_item_launch: assertion 'ctx != NULL' failed
```

So how to fix it ? Thanks !

**I am on Ubuntu 16.04, using PCMandFM-Qt 0.10.0**

Comment: Are `atool` and  `oxygen icons` installed ?

Comment: @MichaelD. Yes `atool`, Oxygen icon and Oxygen5 icons are installed.

Comment: I know your question is more specific, but just in case: I use PCManFM 1.2.4 insted of `pcmanfm-qt`, and  also have Nautilus installed on a ubuntu-16.06-based system, and the actions (including sub-menus) created for Nautilus in Nautilus actions config tool are then appearing in PCManFM. You might want to try that as a last resort, putting your actions through Nautilus actions config tool.

Comment: what desktop environment are you in?

Comment: a comment under the bug report linked in my answer says that **0.10 has to be considered as seriously outdated by now**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug , reported here: https://github.com/lxde/pcmanfm-qt/issues/155.

Meanwhile if you must use the very same actions that you intended to use and in the same way (the ones in `/.local/share/file-manager/actions`), I suggest to switch to PCManFM 1.2.4 (no conflicts with the Qt version) or Nautilus.

Otherwise,  for other actions that can be created - maybe Thunar.

---

Creating actions in  **Nautilus actions configuration tool**, the same actions appear exactly in **PCManFM 1.2.4** (as specified here: https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM#Add_own_options_to_the_files_context_menu). I was also able to add actions manually  according to the link you posted.

Installing **PCManFM-qt 0.10.0** (there's no conflict between them it seems) the toplevel menu entries are displayed but not working (the Nautilus tool can create multi-level menus/submenus but they are not even seen in  **PCManFM-qt 0.10.0**, while in **PCManFM 1.2.4** they appear just like in Nautilus). In **PCManFM-qt 0.10.0** none of the added menus work, not even if manually putting the files in all-user/admin `usr/share/file-manager/actions`.

Comment: I think I've to use a GTK+ file manager, experimenting for the last time with PCManFM-Qt.

Comment: Dolphin is also a good file manager. In terms of resource usage, it is about the same as Nautilus.

Comment: Installed Nautilus after 4 years and what a mess ! Client side window decoration ! I'll never install any Gnome thing, and I'll stick with the original PCManFM.  Dolphin is good, but really hate that `baloo` thing. Anyway, here's your bounty, thanks Cipricus.

Comment: @Arnab - sorry that you got into unpleasant experience with that - what is the desktop that you use? - PCManFM is a way to go no matter the desktop.

Comment: @Cipricus I use LXQt with minimal Kwin, And I use only three GTK+ application, Chromium, KiCad and currently PCManFM. Yes PCManFM and Thunar fits quite well with LXQt desktop.

Answer (score 0):

PCManFM-Qt version 0.14.1 has custom actions through desktop files in `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions` (that can be created with `nautilus-actions`).

It also has split-view (F6).